# fb.api; post from non-app developer's acoount

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have created a simple app which used FB Javascript SDK which posts on FB the things which are given in my webpage's textareas.
I am using fb.api for this and the problem is that it works only with my user id(from which I have created the app). For other ids, it doesn't work.Can someone help please? I want other users also to be able to post on their wall once they are logged in.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <label>Give your message here:</label><br/>
    <textarea id = "ta"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Any image?</label><br/>
    <textarea id = "pic"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Any link?</label><br/>
    <textarea id = "ta_link"></textarea><br/>
    <button onclick = "testAPI()">Click To Post!</button>
    <script>
      // Additional JS functions here
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'AppID', // App ID
          channelUrl : 'http://127.0.0.1/channel.html', // Channel File
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });


        // Additional init code here
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("Connected");
                //testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not_authorized
                login();
            } else {
                // not_logged_in
                login();
            }
        });
        };
         function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //testAPI();
                } else {
                    alert("Can't connect")
                }
            });
        }
      function testAPI() {
          FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
          var tbmsg = document.getElementById("ta").value;
           var tbimg = document.getElementById("pic").value;
           var tblink = document.getElementById("ta_link").value;
          var wallPost = {};
        wallPost['message'] = tbmsg;
        if(tbmsg == "")
        {
            alert("Message box can't be empty")
        }

        if(tbimg)
        {
            wallPost['picture'] = tbimg;
        }
        if(tblink)
        {
            wallPost['link'] = tblink;
        }

        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
        } else {
        alert("Posted");
        }

    });
}
else
{
    alert("Login first")
}
```

});
}

```
      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You probably have to set the domain name correctly in your FB app.

Comment: But what if I am on localhost? Given a domain name, will other users be able to post on their wall?

Comment: make sure your app in not in `sandbox mode`

Comment: you can add a hostname in your hosts file, so you can test the application on localhost with the correct domain name

Comment: It may sound too trivial, but can you please tell me how it can be done? I have just 1 HTML file (containing the above code).

Comment: if you are in windows, the hosts file is in c\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. In unix is in /etc/hosts. There you just have to add an entry like this: 127.0.0.1 my.domain.name.com and you can test the file on that url http://my.domain.name.com/file.html